# Can I use my existing wiring for my new oven?

Tags: oven

My new oven requires 30 amps. The existing wiring is two 20 amp breakers with 14 gauge wiring.

Can I just use my old breakers and old wiring?

Comment: I reworded the title to match up with the question so a simple "Yes" or "No" would answer both. As it was, they were asking for opposite answers.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer is NO.

30 amps requires 10 gauge wire to comply with code and be legal.

20 amps requires 12 gauge wire. *Right now you are not legal*. Your insurance can and will deny any claim if they find it (do not think they won't, it is what they live for).

You will need to change the breaker and change the wires to 10 gauge.

14 gauge can only be on 15 amp breakers.